# Installing Laravel 5 on CentOS

Tags: laravel, centos

I'm trying to install larvel 5 on my vps(the os is centos) and  when I run the command

```html
 php composer.phar create-project laravel/laravel --prefer-dist
```

I get this result

```html
Installing laravel/laravel (v5.0.22)
  - Installing laravel/laravel (v5.0.22)
    Loading from cache
```

then it's stop !

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why your cache is failing, but did you try using source instead of distr?

```
php composer.phar create-project laravel/laravel --prefer-source
```

Comment: Also did you try composer's diagnose? 
     php composer.phar diagnose

Comment: didn't work either , i get : Installing laravel/laravel (v5.0.22)

Comment: when I run diagnose I get this : Checking platform settings: , then it stops !

Comment: Did you run it in verbose to get as much text as possible? php composer.phar -vvv diagnose (add the three v's for as much verbosity) Maybe that will give more info to diagnose the issue. _(also you can try to clear composers cache with clear-cache but I don't think that will help since you aren't using it in diagnose)_

Comment: Sorry I don't have a better answer for you. I tried searching around SO and google but couldn't find anything else relevant. Good luck.